# Trying to create a pdf from html using Nreco pdf converter, not able to load images from amazon cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, pdf-generation, nreco

Trying to create a pdf from html using Nreco pdf converter, html contains images which were loaded properly when loading it from same domain, we have amazon cloud for images so all the images are moved to amazon, and the url is something like this :

> **https://******//api/file/get?path=stage/media/***media/productimages/productimages/image10161107_2.jpeg**

***** => site url
now the images are blank after generating pdf, and there is no log of any exception.

and my code goes like this.

```
    pdfByte = PDFConverter.GeneratePdf(html); 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfByte);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                Response.Buffer = true;
                ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
```